# How to combine result sets of a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html

I am having 5 checkbox with the food items like Chicken, fruits, vegetables, Snacks,.. like that.

What i am trying to implement is when the user selects the checkbox items and clicks submit, it will search for the restaurants providing the selected items,

Table will have 2 fields: restid, menu and the data is stored like this in the table

```
restid->1, menu->chicken
restid->1, menu->Burger
restid->2, menu->fruits
restid->3, menu->chicken
```

My doubt is how to search for the restaurants in the table. My plan is, loop through the for loop for each item with the select statement like (select * from restaurant_table where menu='menu';)

when we loop through the loop how can we combine the results for each menu?

Plz help any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this question.  What do you mean by "combine the results for each menu?"  If you do a `SELECT restid FROM restaurant_table WHERE menu='foo'`, you'll get the ID of each restaurant serving foo.  If you want to search for more than one thing, do a SQL `INTERSECT` or `AND`.

Comment: My answer withdrawn, owing to the obvious defect kindly pointed out by Col. Shrapnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope you are having two table restaurant and menu

restaurant - restid, name

menu  - menuid, restid, menu

the php code can be like this

```
<?php 
     //$_POST['menus'] is the array of checkboxes
     foreach($_POST['menus'] as $menu)
     {
        if($menu) $selected[]=intval($menu);
     }
     $selectedlist=implode(",",$selected);

    //The SQL Query
    $query="SELECT name from restaurant WHERE menu in(".$selectedlist.")";
    $record=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); //Loop this to get more records
?>
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: Is it returns the restaurants whith both the menus selected (AND)  or single menu present (OR)

Comment: @Raja how many tables you've got? single one? Or two, as proposed by sirinvas and as it should be?

Comment: i hav one table  restaurant table with restid and menu

Comment: @Rajasekar it is better to normalize the table as i mentioned or you can use it as you mentioned single table but i prefer to use two table. and the code returns the restaurants for the selected menus (AND)

Answer (score 1):

The query below will return you the restids for restaurants that have both chicken *and* burger on the menu - assuming that restaurant_table doesn't have duplicate rows.

```
SELECT restid, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM restaurant_table
WHERE menu IN ('chicken', 'burger')
GROUP BY restid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Could use `count(distinct menu)` instead of `count(*)` to deal with duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you as starting point:

```
$where = " 1=1 ";

if ( $_POST["chicken"] ) 
$where = $where . " AND menu = 'chicken' ";

if ( $_POST["Burger"] ) 
$where = $where . " AND menu = 'Burger' ";

if ( $_POST["fruits"] ) 
$where = $where . " AND menu = 'fruits' ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE " + $where;
```

Comment: will your query find any row?